# NSArrayController - Observing selectionIndex

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I try setting up observation of this specific key, nothing happens. Here is what I mean.

I have a standard Cocoa application, with an NSTableView, and I figured out how to change the image shown in an image view based on what cell was selected.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to disable/enable buttons by the selected index. What I mean by this, is that I have a button in the window, that is disabled on certain indexes.

SomeClass's init method

```
-(id)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        [arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndex" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }
}
```

However, when I implement the observeValueForKeyPath: method, the changes are not being picked up as I pick new indexes. As a matter of fact, the outlet shows (null) if I try logging it. However, when I add the observer in AppDelegate, AppDelegate (when specified as the observer) picks up changes.

Is there some reason my generic SomeClass object does not? Should it be done a different way?

NOTE:

I tried subclassing SomeClass as a NSWindow, then making the window's owner SomeClass, and setting up the observer in awakeFromNib, and this works, but seems like a bad way to do it.

Comment: How and where are you doing the alloc init on SomeClass?  Also, what do you mean by "the outlet shows (null)" -- what outlet?

Comment: The SomeClass has an instance of it being initialized along with the nib window (the blue cube thing) and during the initialize of an instance of SomeClass (And even after), if I do NSLog(@"%@",arrayController), I will get `(null)`. (The arrayController is set up as an outlet)

Comment: Have you checked to see if your init is being called?  If this class's instance is created in the nib, you should put your code in awakeFromNib instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` method happens too early in the process, before the outlets are connected (I think). Putting the code in `awakeFromNib` will work correctly. This is from Apple's docs in the `NSObject` class reference:

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an `awakeFromNib`
>   message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after
>   all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When
>   an object receives an `awakeFromNib` message, it is guaranteed to have
>   all its outlet and action connections already established.

Comment: I read that, and now I'm just wondering if it is a bad idea (because I got it to work) by subclassing my SomeClass as a descendant of NSWindow, and working from there. Everything is fine and dandy now, but in my NSTableView, my program crashes if I click an empty cell (Out of bounds error.) My observe method does something along the lines of `SomeClass *object = [someArray objectAtIndex:[arrayController selectionIndex]]`. Is there a work-around?